# How to get the product of significant digits from $\overline{abc}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

The problem is as follows:

Let $\overline{abc}$ the maximum amount of microfilms stored in a military hospital. If the digits from such amount follows the rule:

$$2a+3b+c=\overset{\circ}{7}$$

$$a-b+c=\overset{\circ}{11}+7$$

Find the product of the significant digits from the number of microfilms in the hospital.

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{224}\\
2.&\textrm{27}\\
3.&\textrm{1}\\
4.&\textrm{56}\\
\end{array}$

Can this problem be solved without modular arithmetics?. I mean using a more precalculus approach.

What I've attempted so far is as follows: (By going in the system of equations as follows)

$2a+3b+c=\overset{\circ}{7}$

$a-b+c=\overset{\circ}{11}+7$

I did multiplied by 3 to the second equation:

$3a-3b+3c=\overset{\circ}{11}+21=\overset{\circ}{11}+10$

$2a+3b+c=\overset{\circ}{7}$

My approach was to eliminate $b$ from the second equation but when attempting to add these equations I came stuck. Can someone help me here?. What's the approach on where to go from here?.

Comment: what does $\overset{\circ}7$ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $\overset{\circ}{7}$ means some multiple of seven.

The equations are essentially the classic divisibility tests. For example $2a+3b+c=\overset{\circ}{7}$ says that $\overline{abc}$ is a multiple of 7 because $\overline{abc}=100a+10+c=2a+3b+c+7(14a+b)$. Similarly $a−b+c=\overset{\circ}{11}+7$ says that $\overline{abc}$ has remainder 7 when divided by 11.

The smallest number that satisfies those two divisibility requirements is 7, but that is not a 3-digit number. You can however add $77=7\cdot 11$ to it any number of times without changing its divisibility properties w.r.t. 7 and 11, so the numbers that satisfy these properties are:
7, 84, 161, 238, 317, 392, 469, 546, 623, 700, 777, 854, 931, and then you get to 4-digit numbers.

The product of their digits is (7, 32,) 6, 48, 21, 54, 216, 120, 36, 0, 343, 160, 27.

The only one of those that is listed in the multiple choice options is 27.

Comment: Your answers are always elegant!. However I don't understand why $7$ also meets the criteria of divisibility by $\overset{\circ}{11}+7$? Is it because $11\cdot 0 +7 =7$?. Is this the reason?. I'm saying this because I don't know if zero does count as a quotient or multiple. By the way, the problem mentioned the **maximum number of microfilms** hence I believe it was referring to $931$ hence $9\times3\times 1=27$. Can you confirm if my earlier assumption regarding **why $7$ also meets the cirteria** is right?